# Asterisk Manager API SIPPeers - Permission Denied

Tags: asterisk

I'm wanting to use the asterisk manager api to show the status of all my SIP lines in a PHP web interface.

I thought I'd start simple and use telnet to see it working.

So I created a user in /etc/asterisk/manager.conf

```
[portal]
secret = password
read = all,system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user
```

Then telnet to localhost on port 5038

This is what I get:

```
asterisk ~ # telnet localhost 5038
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Asterisk Call Manager/1.0
Action: login
Username: portal
Secret: 8u9sdgk
Events: off

Response: Success
Message: Authentication accepted

Action: SIPPeers

Response: Error
Message: Permission denied
```

Why am I getting permission denied?  I thought the user has basically full access?
Do I need to restart asterisk to make this work?  I didn't restart it.  On the other hand, I was able to log in which makes me think that the manager.conf has been reloaded as the portal user didn't exist before.

Any ideas?

Comment: For those reading, this manager interface is very dangerous! it's extremely easy to bring down the entire server with it.  I found out the hard way.  Don't play around with  it on a live system!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SIPPeers you need 'system, all' privileges. So just add 'write=system' after 'read' line

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify manager.conf, add follow:

`read = all,ystem,call,user,dtmf`

`write = all,system,call`

notice: must be add all after write

Comment: Would you care to explain why `all, call, user, dtmf` are also required?